# Slice when character appears

Tags: python, regex, split, slice

I have this string:

```
Sun 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Mon 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Tue 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Wed 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Thu 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Fri 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Sat 10:00am - 10:00pm
```

And I want to extract only the 2 first hours appearing (which would be 10:00am and 10:00pm)

I am trying with slicing and with spliting, but without success.

Comment: I added regex as these questions are almost always solved with it. Basically we are going ot look for the pattern and find all matches and take first 2.

Comment: Can you post the code you're trying to use?

Answer (score 2):

**Regex:**

```
(?<=\s)\d{2}:\d{2}[ap]m
```

will get all the `HH:MM` matches and you need to get the first two using e.g. list slicing `[:2]` when using `re.findall`.

**Without Regex:**

Split on `<br>` tag, then again by whitespace, get the second and last elements:

```
str_.split('<br>')[0].split()
[out[1], out[-1]]
```

**Example:**

```
In [56]: str_ = 'Sun 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Mon 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Tue 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Wed 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Thu 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Fri 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Sat 10:00am - 10:00pm'

In [57]: re.findall(r'(?<=\s)\d{2}:\d{2}[ap]m', str_)[:2]
Out[57]: ['10:00am', '10:00pm']

In [58]: out = str_.split('<br>')[0].split()

In [59]: [out[1], out[-1]]
Out[59]: ['10:00am', '10:00pm']
```

Comment: Why not just `findall('\d{2}:\d{2}[a|p]m',text)` ?

Comment: @danihp yep that was the one I thought about too

Comment: @danihp Because strictly matching a space beforehand, not sure if its necessary here, OP can confirm. Note that, in your `[a|p]`, `|` is taken literally inside `[]`.

Comment: @AntonvBR See above :)

Answer (score 1):

I thought this regex would do:

```
import re

s= 'Sun 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Mon 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Tue 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Wed 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Thu 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Fri 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Sat 10:00am - 10:00pm'

pattern = r'\d{2}:\d{2}[AaPp][Mm]'

timestamps = re.findall(pattern, s)[:2]

print(timestamps)
```

Comment: This is wrong. `|` inside `[]` is treated literally. Either use 1) `[ap]m` or 2) `(a|p)m`.

Comment: @heemayl aahh thank you. I'm still very neeewbie at this.

Comment: Not sure what you meant. An example?

Comment: Like is said in point 2: `(a|p)m` .Note the, `[]` and `()` operators.

Comment: @heemayl yes but what if I wanted to match either am (exact) or pm (exact). I found [AaPp][Mm] to be very clear though.

Comment: The equivalent with `()` would be: `(A|a|P|p)(M|m)`. You might also look at `re.IGNORECASE` for case-insensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex:

```
s = "Sun 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Mon 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Tue 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Wed 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Thu 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Fri 10:00am - 10:00pm<br>Sat 10:00am - 10:00pm"


spl = s.split("<br>")   # split at <br> into the days
d={} # empty dict
for s in spl:  # for each day
    d.setdefault(s.split(" ")[0],[]).extend([x for x in s.split(" ") 
                                             if x!= '-'][1:])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
 {'Wed': ['10:00am', '10:00pm'], 
  'Sun': ['10:00am', '10:00pm'], 
  'Fri': ['10:00am', '10:00pm'], 
  'Tue': ['10:00am', '10:00pm'], 
  'Mon': ['10:00am', '10:00pm'], 
  'Thu': ['10:00am', '10:00pm'], 
  'Sat': ['10:00am', '10:00pm']}
```

It splits your data into days (at `<br>`) and splits each day into its weekday (as key) and the both times into a list, omitting the day which we already took as key for the dict and the `-` that is between the times.

You get to the list of times of Tue by  `tueTime = d['Tue']` and can access it by `[0] or [1]` or by decomposing `open,close = tueTime`.

---

If you only need the first one, do use: `spl = s.split("<br>")[0]` - the dict is unordered and you wont know which one was first in your data string.

Comment: No need for regex sure but for extracting text from strings there is really no need not to use regex. It's easy to understand and adapt to new situations.